# NPE With EJB 3 & WASCE

Tags: jax-rs, ejb-3.0

I've been banging my head against this for a while and figured I'd finally ask for help/ideas of why my EJBs aren't being injected correctly.  I'm using Java 6 w/ EJB 3 & WAS Community Edition with Apache Wink and keep getting a NPE when trying to access the ITestService.  If I try to look up the bean in the context it throws a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException.  Is there something I'm missing/else I have to do to get the bean added to the context?

Application Class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add( TestResource.class );   
        return resources;
    }
}
```

The bean's interface

```
@Local
public interface ITestService {
    public String test();
}
```

The bean's implementation class

```
@Singleton
public class TestService implements ITestService {

    @Override
    public String test() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

JAX-RS Resource

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Stateless
public class TestResource {
    @EJB
    private ITestService service;
    @GET
    public Response test() {
        String value = service.test();
        return Response.ok( value ).build();
    }   
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<description>My Web Application</description>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.gordysc.myfit.server.servlets.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

geronimo-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-2.0.1"
     xmlns:naming="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/naming-1.2"
     xmlns:sys="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment-1.2">
<context-root>/myfit</context-root>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Still have no idea how to solve this.. it looks like EJBs aren't being added to the context for WASCE... do I have to use a specific geronimo deployment descriptor to take advantage of EJB3?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar head banging experience. I ended up abandoning EJB injection in favor of a JNDI lookup approach:

Added to my web.xml:

```
<ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/MyEJBLocal</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>com.test.ejb.MyEJBLocal</local>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

Then in my web service implementation class:

```
javax.naming.Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
MyEJBLocal myEJB = 
       (MyEJBLocal) jndiContext.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/MyEJBLocal");
```

Did you have any luck with EJB injection? If so, please let me know what you did. If not, I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, sorry this is extremely late.  For some reason, I didn't get notifications on this and literally just got an e-mail.  I ended up going from WASCE over to TomEE actually.  I haven't had a chance to see how this interacts with Liberty 8.5.5.1 (https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/), but I don't think it would (I don't believe it supports EJBs at the moment?).  I know WASCE has an end of market announcement (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21449999), but I do hope your solution helps someone else out that's hitting a similar issue.  Sorry for the sloth response!